# Pinterest API : is it possible to get secret boards?

Tags: pinterest

Is there a way to fetch the list of the logged user's secret boards using the Pinterest API ?

I can't find it and I suppose it does not support it (which is odd); but I just want to be sure !

Also, if I have a Pinterest (secret) board ID; will the API be able to retrieve its pins ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As of today, Pinterest does not support secret boards with APIs.
https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/boards/